# Separate bank account / finances from Schedule C sole-proprietorship for single member "disregarded entity" LLC

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, limited-liability-company, schedule-c

If having a Schedule C business and then starting a single member LLC (i.e. which the IRS views as a disregarded entity for tax purposes), should a separate bank account / expense tracking need to be opened for the LLC vs the Schedule C business if they are both engaged in the same activity by the same person?

Wondering if any implications on tax filing or on LLC protection implications or otherwise.

Comment: Purely for the sake of 'cleanliness' [ease of recordkeeping, etc.], I would say it is always 'recommended' to have separate bank accounts for business. Not an answer because I'm not sure what types of "implications" you are concerned with - it seems mostly you are concerned if this gets to the point of being a requirement.

Comment: Two different companies should never share a bank account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more of a legal question than a tax question. The IRS doesn't care about your bank accounts, it cares about your income (the R stands for Revenue).

In order to protect yourself from [piercing the corporate veil](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/piercing_the_corporate_veil) of the LLC, you have to ensure to treat is as a completely separate *legal* (not tax) entity from yourself, and that includes having separate bank accounts.

You would probably want a proper legal advice from a lawyer.